# PHP Combobox last selected same after changing page

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, combobox

Can all help me with my php. i can keep my combobox not changing after reload. but after im changing a page in my paging. it not work can you help me?

THIS IS MY PHP.

PHP

**Category :** 
                    
                        >All
                        >Computer
                        >Peripheral
                        >Gadget

---

";
                    else
                    echo "";
                    echo "

### Category : **".$baris["Category"]."**

";
                    echo "  ";
                    echo "      ";
                    echo "  ";
                    echo "  ";
                    echo "

#### Nama : ".$baris["Nama"]. "

";
                    echo "       **Harga       :** Rp. ".$newprice. "";
                    echo "       **Keterangan  :** 
".$baris['Keterangan']."";
                    echo "  ";
                    echo "";
                    echo "
";
                    $no=$no+1;
                }
                ?>
            
            
                $i ";

                    }   
                ?>

```
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            (C)
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies on the line (roughly 101;):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=$jum_page;$i++){
    echo "<a href = index.php?page=$i>$i</a> ";
}
```

The middle line should read:

```
echo "<a href=index.php?page=$i&choice=$selected_choice>$i</a> ";
```

This will ensure that the combo box choice is preserved across pages. Is this problem you were experiencing?